# Header function in VBA

Tags: vba, function, excel, columnheader

I have a function in Excel VBA that searches for headers and uses them to define certain ranges.  It looks like it would work perfectly fine but when I call it, it breaks on this line: `Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange, Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(ROW_HEADERS))`  and I am not sure why.  It gives me a subscript out of range error.  The sheetName variable is a string and the sheet Sheet8 (that I am passing into it) does exist. I have posted the entire function below in addition to the line where I call it in the Sub.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function FindHeader(HEADER_NAME As String, sheetName As String) As Range

    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngHdrFound As Range

    Const ROW_HEADERS As Integer = 1

    Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange, Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(ROW_HEADERS))
    Set rngHdrFound = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME)

    If rngHdrFound Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("ERROR: Cannot find appropriate header.")
        Exit Function
    End If

  Set FindHeader = Range(rngHdrFound.Offset(1), rngHdrFound.End(xlDown))

End Function
```

Line that calls it:

```
Sheet8.Activate
sheetName = "Sheet8"
Set rng1 = FindHeader("Client Exclusion List", sheetName)
```

Comment: It doesn't even get to that line...It breaks on the line before `rngHdrFound` is defined.

Comment: Can you try the following in the line that calls your function: Change the second [`sheetName = "Sheet8"`] line to `sheetName = Sheet8.Name`

Comment: ahhh my bad, thought it was breaking on `Set FindHeader...`

Comment: If you do `MsgBox Worksheets(sheetName).Name` what happens?

Comment: @user3561813 that worked! must have been something with the name! thanks!

Comment: @Philip I'll add an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA distinguishes between a Worksheets `.Name` property and the `.CodeName` property. `.CodeName` refers to the name visible in the VBA Project Tree View (usually Sheet1, Sheet2, etc). The `.Name` is found in parenthesis right after the `.CodeName`. Additionally, the `.Name` is the value in the Worksheet Tab on the Excel front end.

If you pass the `.CodeName` to the `Worksheets` Collection, it will generate an error (unless the `.CodeName` and `.Name` are identical).

Hopefully this helps.